# Get json data and filter by parameter, then pass it to ion-slide-box (ionic slider)

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have some troubles trying to filter or get just the data from a json file based on the parameter received in $stateParams

**Controller:**

```
.controller('fieldImages', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate){
//Get Field images
$scope.field_images = [];

//Get Field id 
$scope.fieldId = $stateParams.Id_soccer_field;

$http.get('http://demo.htgsolutions.com/icancha/soccer_field_images.json').
    success(function(data) {         
        $scope.field_images = data[$scope.fieldId];
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('image-viewer').update();
    }).
    error(function(data) {
      // log error
      console.log("Error"+  data);
    });
```

})

when I inspect on console I see that the object is correctly loaded:

```
{ Id_soccer_field_image: "3", Id_soccer_field: "2", image_path: "http://demo.htgsolutions.com/icanch…", image_name: "Imagen cancha test" }

{ Id_soccer_field_image: "2", Id_soccer_field: "1", image_path: "http://demo.htgsolutions.com/icanch…", image_name: "Imagen cancha test" }
```

But then when binding the data as ng-repeat on the img-src is not loading the images on the slider...
**View:**
`<ion-slide-box pager-click="navSlide(index)" delegate-handle="image-viewer" show-pager='true' does-continue="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="images in field_images">
        <img ng-src="{{images.image_path}}" />
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the {{images.image_path}} empty?

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.field_images))`?  Instead of trying to fill the <img> tag can you just try to print out the content to the screen?

Comment: I just tested console.log("json:", JSON.stringify($scope.field_images)) and I got "{"Id_soccer_field_image":"2","Id_soccer_field":"1","image_path":"http://demo.htgsolutions.com/icancha/cancha4.jpg","image_name":"Imagen cancha test"}"

Comment: So it returned an object, but your ng-repeat is expecting an array.  So instead of `$scope.field_images =` you're going to want `$scope.field_images.push(data[$scope.fieldId])` which pushes an object into your array.  Let me know if that treats you better :-)